# How do I print random items from a list without repetition?

Tags: python, list, random

I am in the early stages of learning at the moment and I'm attempting to make a simple little memory game.

The problem I am having is printing a different random item constantly until the list has been exhausted, whilst giving the user a little time between each output to remember it.

```
import random

List1 = ['item' , 'item' , 'ect']

Print(random.choice(List1))

input('press enter for next item')
```

Comment: what is the output? Why are you using capital P for print?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is a [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Answer (score 2):

Your simplest solution is probably to shuffle the list, then iterate over the shuffled list.

```
my_list = ['item' , 'item' , 'ect']
random.shuffle(my_list)   # my_list is now in random order

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

If for some reason you want to preserve the original order as well, make a copy of the list before shuffling it. (`my_copy = my_list.copy()`)

Comment: Also note the variable name choice `my_list`. You should in general not give variables capitalized names (there are certain special uses for those), or names like `list` that mean something to Python itself.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you.